# Como agrupar um array de objetos em javascript (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, objetos

Como ler um array de objetos e retorna apenas objetos que contém o mesmo valor em vários atributos?
Fiz esse array de objetos como exemplo.

```
var arrayDeObjetos = [
  {"dia":1 , "desc":"Nigth","mes":1},
  {"dia":1 , "Descricao":"Brilha","mes":1},
  {"dia":2 , "desc":"Urna","mes":2},
  {"dia":3 , "Descricao":"Covas","mes":1},
  {"dia":2 , "desc":"Mario Corvas","mes":1},
  {"dia":4 , "Desc":"Estrelas","mes":2}
];
```

Nesse Array eu tenho vários objetos eu queria agrupar todos e um novo array que contem um objeto com  todos que contem `dia = 1` e `mes = 1` outro objeto que contém todos com `dia = 2` e `mes = 2`
O resultado final tem que ser algo como

```
var resultado = [
  [
    {"dia":1,"mes":1,"desc":"descricao AQI"},
    {"dia":1,"mes":1,"desc":"Outra desc"}
  ],
  [
    {"dia":2,"mes":2,"desc":"outro mes"},
    {"dia":1,"mes":1,"desc":"outra coisa"}
  ]];
```

Comment: Há "N" formas de fazer isso, desde iterações com _forEach_ ou _for_, ou usando o método _map()_ > mais informações dele aqui: [W3Schools - Map](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp). Ou também, utilizar uma biblioteca muito boa que irá facilitar sua vida, chama-se [LinqJS](https://github.com/mihaifm/linq).

Comment: O resultado é esse mesmo ou você quis dizer que em cada índice do array contenha os objetos com mesmo dia e mesmo mês?

Comment: Joao, no `resultado` que tens na pergunta tens `dia 1` e `mês 1` em ambas... é erro?

Comment: @Sergio foi erro de digitação meu

Comment: Ok. Podes corrigir na pergunta? eu gostava de dar uma resposta mas quero ter a certeza do resultado que esperas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o array de objetos for muito extenso, você pode separar um array de objetos não duplicados mapeando os dias e meses e então filtrar com base no que foi descoberto.

```
var arrayDeObjetos = [
  {"dia":1 , "desc":"Nigth","mes":1},
  {"dia":1 , "Descricao":"Brilha","mes":1},
  {"dia":2 , "desc":"Urna","mes":2},
  {"dia":3 , "Descricao":"Covas","mes":1},
  {"dia":2 , "desc":"Mario Corvas","mes":1},
  {"dia":4 , "Desc":"Estrelas","mes":2}
];
```

Irá se tornar em `objetosASeparar`:

```
objetosASeparar = [
  {dia: 1, mes: 1},
  {dia: 2, mes: 2}
]
```

Então caso houver dia 3 e mês 3, dia 4 e mês 4 assim por diante, todos serão filtrados em um novo objeto.

```js
var arrayDeObjetos = [
  {"dia":1 , "desc":"Nigth","mes":1},
  {"dia":1 , "Descricao":"Brilha","mes":1},
  {"dia":2 , "desc":"Urna","mes":2},
  {"dia":3 , "Descricao":"Covas","mes":1},
  {"dia":2 , "desc":"Mario Corvas","mes":1},
  {"dia":4 , "Desc":"Estrelas","mes":2}
];

// obter um array de objetos com dia e mes não duplicados
var objetosASeparar = [];
arrayDeObjetos.filter(item => item.dia == item.mes).map(function(item){
  if(item.dia == item.mes){
    return {
      dia: item.dia,
      mes: item.mes
      }
  }
}).forEach(function(a){
  if (objetosASeparar.length == 0) objetosASeparar.push(a);
  objetosASeparar.forEach(function(b){
    if (b.dia !== a.dia && b.mes !== a.mes)
      objetosASeparar.push(a);
  });
});

// filtrados com base nos objetos descobertos
var novoObjeto = {};
objetosASeparar.forEach(function(a,i){
    novoObjeto[i] = arrayDeObjetos.filter(b => a.dia == b.dia && a.mes == b.mes);
});

console.log(novoObjeto);
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira é utilizando o [Javascript Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) para encontrar somente os valores que precisa e inserí-los em um novo array utilizando o `push`, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
var arrayDeObjetos = [
  {"dia":1 , "desc":"Nigth","mes":1},
  {"dia":1 , "Descricao":"Brilha","mes":1},
  {"dia":2 , "desc":"Urna","mes":2},
  {"dia":3 , "Descricao":"Covas","mes":1},
  {"dia":2 , "desc":"Mario Corvas","mes":1},
  {"dia":4 , "Desc":"Estrelas","mes":2}
];

var novoArray = [];

novoArray.push(filtrarArray(arrayDeObjetos, 1, 1));
novoArray.push(filtrarArray(arrayDeObjetos, 2, 2));

console.log(novoArray);

function filtrarArray(array, dia, mes) {
  return array.filter(function(val) {
    return val.dia === dia && val.mes === mes;  
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça

```
var objetos = [
   {"dia":1 , "desc":"Nigth","mes":1},
   {"dia":1 , "Descricao":"Brilha","mes":1},
   {"dia":1 , "desc":"Nigth","mes":1},
   {"dia":2 , "desc":"Urna","mes":2}
]

var meuNovoArray = [];

angular.forEach(objetos, function(objeto)){
     if(objeto.dia === 1){
         menuNovoArray.push(objeto) //adiciona o obj nesse seu novo array
     }
}
```

Depois basta dar um **console.log(meuNovoArray)** que vai dar certo.

Answer (score 0):

Este tipo de operação é chamada de map reduce, no javascript todo array possui a operação reduce para estes casos. Segue 2 exemplos de como utilizá-la no seu caso.

**Utilizando Objeto:**

```
Object.values([
    {"dia":1 , "desc":"Nigth","mes":1},
    {"dia":1 , "Descricao":"Brilha","mes":1},
    {"dia":2 , "desc":"Urna","mes":2},
    {"dia":3 , "Descricao":"Covas","mes":1},
    {"dia":2 , "desc":"Mario Corvas","mes":1},
    {"dia":4 , "Desc":"Estrelas","mes":2}
  ].reduce(function(prev, item) {
    var key = item.dia * 100 + item.mes;
    prev[key] = prev[key] || [];
    prev[key].push(item);
    return prev;
  }, {})
);
```

**Utilizando Array:**

```
[
  {"dia":1 , "desc":"Nigth","mes":1},
  {"dia":1 , "Descricao":"Brilha","mes":1},
  {"dia":2 , "desc":"Urna","mes":2},
  {"dia":3 , "Descricao":"Covas","mes":1},
  {"dia":2 , "desc":"Mario Corvas","mes":1},
  {"dia":4 , "Desc":"Estrelas","mes":2}
]
.reduce(function(prev, current) {
    var index = prev.findIndex(function(j) { return j.dia == current.dia && j.mes == current.mes});
    if (index < 0) {
        index = prev.length;
        prev.push({
            dia: current.dia,
            mes: current.mes,
            lista: []
        });
    }
    prev[index].lista.push(current);
    return prev;
}, [])
.map(function(item){
    return item.lista;
});
```

Apesar de mais complexo o método utilizando array deve ser mais eficiente que o método utilizando objeto.

**Observação** Não indexe no array o dia e o mês, ex: array[mes*100 + dia], pois na linguagem javascript ele ira criar todas as posições no array até chegar ao valor informado.